# Atlassian Confluence - create blog post with labels using python

Tags: python, confluence

I can create blog post in confluence using the script below:

```
import sys
from xmlrpclib import Server

user = "user"
passwd = "pass"
serverurl = "<blah-blah>/xmlrpc"
spacekey = "DEV"

s = Server( serverurl )
token = s.confluence1.login( user, passwd )

newblogpostdata = {"title":"title", 
               "content":"content", 
               "space":spacekey}
newblogpostdata = s.confluence1.storeBlogEntry(token, newblogpostdata)
```

But couldn't find how to add some labels to the blog post?

Update. Finally I used the following solution:
    id = newblogpost['id']
    s.confluence1.addLabelByName(token, "ctrm", id)

Comment: If you click the "Edit This Page" button and scroll to the bottom there will be a button you can click which says "Labels" and from there you can add labels. So there is at least an easy option for adding labels after the blog post has already been made.

Comment: According to some comments at the bottom of this page: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Adding+Labels there is no way to add labels to blog posts, only pages themselves

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using macros in your content?

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+Label+Macros+to+Categorise+Wiki+Content

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+Wiki+Markup+for+Macros

But you would have to experiment to find proper syntax I am afraid.